# QGIS: Loading a CSV of points as a line

Tags: qgis, line, csv

I have a CSV file downloaded from a GPS tracking system. Every row contains `lat`, `lon`, `timestamp`, and `row no`. How can I load it into QGIS as a line layer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have QGIS in front of me at the moment, so this is from memory:

1. Load the csv as points (you may have to subsequently save them as a layer, such as a shape file or geopackage)
2. Use the Points to Paths plugin tool to convert the points to lines.
3. Voila!